# Spring security issue with Http tag

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My spring configuration file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    ">

<http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

However I have encountered the following error

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
```

What could possibly be wrong? The error cross mark as shown by Eclipse is right where http tag starts.

UPDATE
I am using gradle and my build.gradle file has following dependencies for Spring:

```
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile 'de.grundid.opendatalab:geojson-jackson:1.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4+'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4+'
```

The following Spring dependencies are in my project's build path:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your pom. Xml details for spring security

Comment: Hey @MdFaraz please check the updated part:).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XML document has the Spring beans namespace as default namespace. The `http` element and the other elements from Spring Security are in the security namespace. You need to prefix:

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
      <security:user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Hi after adding the security namespace I have encountered another error:             Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:http'.
 - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd', 
  because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

Comment: @Smrita that XSD is returning a 404 from the browser, that's the problem.  The namespace config from my [spring security file](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml) may be of help, the security XSD it's using (http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd) pops up fine.

Comment: The 404 is normal, the xsd should be found in classpath, but if a version-specific xsd works for you, go with that.